# image from sqlite db and html in uiwebview

Tags: html, sql, ios, image

please hepl if some body had same problem...
I have sqlite db, with images in NSData. I need to insert image in uiwebview but... the image do not show....

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                   @"<html> <head>"
                   @"<style> body { font-family:Verdana;font-size:13px;}</style>"
                   @"</head>"
                   @"<img src=\"%@\" />"
                   @"<br/>%@"
                   @"</body> </html>", datePicture,strDescription]] ;
```

And then i insert it in UIWebview:

```
[descripWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: images in NSDate??? Did you mean NSData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `datePicture` is of type `UIImage`, you could encode the image in base64 and embed that directly to your HTML.

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                   @"<html> <head>"
                   @"<style> body { font-family:Verdana;font-size:13px;}</style>"
                   @"</head>"
                   @"<img src=\"data:Image/jpeg;base64,%@\" />"
                   @"<br/>%@"
                   @"</body> </html>", 
       [QSStrings encodeBase64WithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((datePicture, 1.0)],
       strDescription];
```

Note that I'm using QSStrings to do the encoding, which can be found in [QSUtilities on github](https://github.com/mikeho/QSUtilities)